# In WPF, how do I emphasize the top row of a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a listview in WPF that currently looks like this:

[image: Current Listview]

and is generated from this code:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Author}" Header="Author"/>
      <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MessageShort}" Header="Message"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I would like to visually emphasize or distinguish the first item (the Unsaved Changes line in the picture). This is not a header, but the item to emphasize will always be the first. Is it possible to do so cleanly in WPF, whether from XAML or code?

My research has showed things like using Triggers and/or [ItemTemplateSelectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8), but both seem like way too much when the only logic is "is the first element". I also found [AlternationIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex?view=netframework-4.8) and [AlternationCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationcount?view=netframework-4.8) and could conceivably set the AlternationCount to some number high enough to never be used and give different templates to AlternationIndex 1 and the rest, though this feels like a hack and still non-trivial. Not to mention I'm not quite sure how to implement it and to make sure it doesn't interfere with the GridView.

Changing style or template properties for a fixed position doesn't seem like it should be a difficult thing to do, but I can't seem to figure it out. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: There are a few ways to accomplish this. You could create a Brush property in your class and bind the rows background to it, or you could use a converter and bind it to the index. If the index is 0, it changes the color. Are you familiar with Converters?

Comment: @Tronald I started to mess around with them a bit, would this be the most idiomatic way? In which template/view should I use the converter? 

As for brush property, I don't know how to bind a specific row's property in the ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest thing for you would probably be to just add a `Brush` property to your class that you can bind too. You can set this property value based on your requirements.

Note: `Brush` requires reference to `System.Windows.Media`

In your class add.

```
//Adjust getter/setter if using iNotifyPropertyChanged
public Brush MyBrush { get; set; } = Brushes.White;
```

Now bind the `ListView` row background to the property.

```xml
<ListView Name="listView" >
   <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MyBrush}"/>
        </Style>
   </ListView.Resources>
   <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Author}" Header="Author"/>
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MessageShort}" Header="Message"/>
        </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you, the Style and Setter tags were exactly what I needed. I already have a boolean property for this first element anyway, which is semantically better. I'm actually going to bind to the FontWeight property instead of Brush, at least in this prototyping phase, and use a ValueConverter, but this is definitely the clean approach I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, glad I could help.

Comment: @Tronald, what will happen with highlighted row after sorting?

Comment: @ASh since the row is bound to an item's property within a collection, the highlighted background will remain with the item that's intended to be highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

Binding to PreviousData should do the trick:

```
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Very cool, I didn't know about the PreviousData binding, that's definitely another clean way to solve this problem!